# Read images in SQL table row by row

Tags: c#, sql, image

I have a very big database, which has a table called `Table1`. The table has two columns: `ID` and `Images`.

In column "Images", there is an image in each row. How can I read these images and save them to a separate file by iterating over the rows one by one.

Note that since the table is very big. I cannot read the entire table into memory, and so I need to read rows one by one. Any solution in C#? Thanks!

Comment: I would use pagination in that case.

Comment: Why not achiving it in sql using cursor??

Comment: There is probably a solution but we need to know about your database (how do you store the image in the image column), how do you connect to your database ? Did you already try something ?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Use EntityFramework on top of your database. Then do this:

```
foreach (var imgRecord in dataRepository.Table1)
{
  var img = imgRecord.Image;
  // TODO: Do whatever
}
```

EF will read it one by one.